# "The description for Event ID" when using EntryWrittenEventHandler to access Event Message

Tags: .net, event-log

We are using the following .NET 4.5 code to capture event log entries as they are created:

```
var log = new EventLog("Application");
log.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
log.EntryWritten += new EntryWrittenEventHandler(OnEntryWritten);

// Define other methods and classes here
protected static void OnEntryWritten(object source, EntryWrittenEventArgs evt)
{
    var e = evt.Entry;
    var v = new
    {
        EntryType = e.EntryType,
        Index = e.Index,
        InstanceId = e.InstanceId,
        MachineName = e.MachineName,
        Message = e.Message,
        Source = e.Source,
        TimeGenerated = e.TimeGenerated.ToUniversalTime(),
        TimeWritten = e.TimeWritten.ToUniversalTime(),
        UserName = e.UserName,
    };
    v.Dump(); //Testing in LinqPad
}
```

However the entries are showing the following as their Message:

> The description for Event ID '1903' in Source 'HHCTRL' cannot be
>   found.  The local computer may not have the necessary registry
>   information or message DLL files to display the message, or you may
>   not have permission to access them.  The following information is part
>   of the event:'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=45839'

and

> The description for Event ID '1' in Source 'scollector' cannot be
>   found.  The local computer may not have the necessary registry
>   information or message DLL files to display the message, or you may
>   not have permission to access them.  The following information is part
>   of the event:'service_windows.go:194: scollector service stopped'

These messages appear correctly in the Event Viewer (no error about the description) and they also appear correct when I view them using `get-winevent -LogName Application -MaxEvents 10` in Powershell.

I tried adding the following [PermissionSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlogpermission%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to make sure I have access to the event log, but it still doesn't work.

```
PermissionSet ps = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.Unrestricted);
ps.AddPermission(new RegistryPermission(RegistryPermissionAccess.AllAccess, System.Environment.MachineName));
ps.AddPermission(new EventLogPermission(EventLogPermissionAccess.Administer, System.Environment.MachineName));
ps.Demand();
```

The service (or LinqPad when we are testing) is running as administrator and I have confirmed that the `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Application\scollector\EventMessageFile` registry key exists (our custom service just uses `%SystemRoot%\System32\EventCreate.exe` so that all message formats are just %1 ). What do we need to do to prevent the "The description for Event ID" error message from being included in the entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it appears that the applications that were not working correctly were using a REG_SZ registry type for EventMessageFile instead of the REG_SZ_EXPAND registry type (which expands the %SystemRoot% to c:\Windows before returning the value).

[image: EventMessageFile]

[REG_SZ_EXPAND is the required type](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3183/Enhanced-EventLog-writing-for-NET-Applications#pre0), but in our case these were registered using just REG_SZ due to a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/winsvc/issues/detail?id=12&thanks=12&ts=1426706536) in the [winsvc/eventlog go package](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/winsvc/eventlog)

Once I deleted and recreated the EventMessageFile key with the correct type it started working as expected.